# How to make a container with tabview & listview occupy space upto bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have implemented tab layout which consists of two tabs, each tab view has a listview, container with tabview & listview should occupy space upto bottom as of now i place static value of 400, so only up to 400 the listview appears, i need the list view to be appeared up to bottom. can you please me to fix this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,right:20.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: new TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                tabs: [
                  new Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.description),
                    text: 'ABC',
                  ),
                  new Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.assignment),
                    text: 'XYZ',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,right:20.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 400.0,
              child: new TabBarView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Sun'),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Moon'),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Star'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Sun'),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Moon'),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Star'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Used `Expanded` & `Flex` Widgets which solved the problem

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,right:20.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new TabBar(
                  controller: _controller,
                  labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                  tabs: [
                    new Tab(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.description),
                      text: 'Current Openings',
                    ),
                    new Tab(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.assignment),
                      text: 'Applied Jobs',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,right:20.0,bottom: 10.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new TabBarView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Sun'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Sun'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            flex: 9,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```